# Can I use the "start" command with spaces in the path?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a path like this: `Y:\xxx\dd sss\aaa\ccc`

`Y:\` is mapped to an FTP address. Now when I try to use `start` to open my folder I cannot.
Command prompt makes mistake a and goes to `Y:\xxx\dd` folder!

I already tried to use `%20` instead of a space, but that was also unsuccessful.

I am running this using a batch file from an Oracle form.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Maybe `C:\Windows\explorer.exe /e,"Y:\xxx\dd sss\aaa\ccc"`.

Comment: You scan change to the folder and the drive at the same time at a cmd prompt with `cd /D "Y:\xxx\dd sss\aaa\ccc"`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use quotes like this:

```
start "" "Y:\foo bar\baz"
```

The `start` builtin command can be used to create new console windows, if you give it a console-based program (or nothing at all, in which case it starts the default `cmd.exe` shell).

If the first argument is quoted, `start` assumes it's the title for the new console window, so give it an empty title. The following argument will then be correctly interpreted as the command to run / file to open.

Comment: thanks for the note about the empty quote! Now I finally understand why sometimes a console window opens instead of an Explorer window. :)

Answer (score 8):

Put it in quotation marks like so:

```
start "" "Y:\xxx\dd sss\aaa\ccc"
```

Comment: it's not working -- by run like this just a window of CMD just showing to me... :(

Comment: Remove the `start`.

Comment: Also try `"Y:\\xxx\\dd sss\\aaa\\ccc"`.

Comment: Error: The file name ,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: @rima, does the thing you want actually work for any other path *without* spaces?

Comment: @arjan : yes it will work for another path

Comment: And, @rima, any path also mapped to that FTP server?

Comment: @Arjan : Emmm,no for other I use the address like \\xxxx\dddd\ggg

Comment: @arjan: I guess DOS convert my path to s.th like this Y:\xxx\dd ~1 so first it go to folder dd not to "dd sss"

Comment: @martineau : Without start is impossible also \\ not worked too

Comment: The executable name and the parameters need to be separated, do they not?

Answer (score 3):

You really only need to quote the actual space(s)

For instance:

```
start /wait C:\path\test" "spaced\setup.exe
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score -4):

Put the part with the spaces into quotation marks, eg.:

C:\path\"to something"\file

Your welcome.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is correct.

Comment: In my system, trying to open a pdf file in this way, does nothing