# How to call a program that contains space in filename?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm tried to run a command line something like this: `start /max C:\Program files\foo\ba.exe -somearguments`.

But I have a problem, the cmd returns an error message something like `The system cannot found the C:\Program file` and if I put the `C:\Program files\foo\ba.exe` around quotes, it simply run a new window cmd in MAX mode and don't run the program.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All filenames and paths which contain spaces must be quoted.

Next, regarding your question, how about stating the path like:

```
start /max /d"C:\Program files\foo\" ba.exe -somearguments
```

Comment: This answer is only a partial solution: It will work if there are spaces in the path but it will not work if there are spaces in the filename. Calling ''start "b a.exe" fails.''

Answer (score 18):

The error happened because the system interpreted your command as the file `C:\Program` and `file` as an argument of your command. Obviously it doesn't find the file `Program` and returned this error.

To fix it, just include `""` on the path between the words with the space character or on entire path:

```
start /max C:\"Program files"\foo\ba.exe -somearguments
```

or

```
start /max "C:\Program files\foo\ba.exe" -somearguments
```

Comment: There needs to be a `""` before program path in the second example; see http://superuser.com/a/239572/1686 on why.

Comment: You say I must include it? Ive just tested here now and it worked without "" before...

Comment: It might have changed, then, but `cmd.exe` on Windows XP would require it.

Comment: I've just tried it, and Windows 7 definitely doesn't accept the second example, although the first one works.

Comment: It autocompleted automatically here if start to digit c:Prorg and press TAB.

Comment: And kudos to the person at MicroSoft that decided to use a space in the folder name!

Comment: So unintuitive... but worked for me!!

Answer (score 6):

Although wrapping the path in quotes is the easiest and clearest to read, you can also use the old DOS short names (since DOS followed 8.3 naming, file names longer than 8 characters were truncated with `~1`) for files. These names do not have spaces. You can see the short names for files with the `DIR /X` command.

Comment: I needed a command line to launch conemu from atom text editor inside windows 10. This was the only method that would work for me in that case.

Answer (score 3):

In Win10 you can try this:

```
start /max C:\Program%20files\foo\ba.exe -somearguments
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain what you are suggesting? :)