# How do I make a relative link in windows with a space in the path

Tags: windows, path, symbolic-link

I want to make a relative link in Windows 7 to a path that contains a space character.

Making a relative link *without* a space in the path works as follows (explained [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-to-create-a-shortcut-with-relative-path/3e1b0ede-1e18-4ecd-937b-66756d3409d3)):

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start .\somepath\myfile.xlsx
```

But in my case I have a space in the path:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start .\some path\myfile.xlsx
```

I know that normally you have to wrap your path with double quotes when creating shortcuts. This works well when having *absolute* links.

But the following solutions do not work in my case:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start ".\some path\myfile.xlsx"

%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "start .\some path\myfile.xlsx"
```

I also tried to use other quotes quotes (`´`,`'`) with the above combinations but I did not succeed.

Do you know what I am missing here?

Comment: The real question – quoting the argument to `start` – was already answered in [Can I use the "start" command with spaces in the path?](http://superuser.com/questions/239565/can-i-use-the-start-command-with-spaces-in-the-path).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the previous answer was erroneous. Try this:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start \D<Relative path in double quotes> <Name of file>
```

So for you it would be like,

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start \D"some path" myfile.xlsx
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  When I use  `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "some path\myfile.xlsx"`on my machine it only starts a new cmd.exe window and sets the "some path\myfile.xlsx" as a label for the cmd.exe window. I cannot (or better do not want ;) to have absolute pathes because I have to copy the directory tree to another computer with different drive letters and prefix and it should still work there.

Comment: Severin Winkler, the first "" after start is taken to be a window name. Try interpolating an extra "" between start and "some path".