# How to use .bat to open default program?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, command-line, cmd.exe

Is it possible (using cmd or .bat) to automatically open a text file using the default Windows application?

For example, when opening a .html file, if Chrome is my default browser, the .html will open with Chrome automatically. How can I tell the cmd (or .bat) to open the default program for a particular file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `start` command, which I believe uses ShellExecute():

```
start "" "My text file.txt"
```

(The first empty parameter is [often required](https://superuser.com/q/239565/1686).)

Comment: Thanks. What if there's no document? How would I simply open the default web browser or default text editor?

Comment: @user910404 if this is what you meant to ask in the first place, please edit your question to indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

That is what the `START` command is for.
`START <name of document>`
will load the document in the default application.