# How to prevent the CMD pause to stop the script after opening a program

Tags: cmd.exe, basic

So, I am very bad at using the CMD program and I'm just trying to do something for fun. In my mind, it is very basic. I want to open a .bat file, that prompt an "echo" question so when I press any key it opens a program A and a URL X, then ask me again if I want to open another program B by pressing any key.

My problem is that it works **only** if the first program is already open on my PC. If it's not, it only prompts the first "echoes", open my URL , then nothing else happen. Ctrl+Z doesn't seem to resume the script to the next line.

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
@echo off
color 0a
title MY TITLE
echo -Welcome
echo -Do you want to do something ?
echo -I can open "an URL X" and "a program A"
pause
start https://URL X
"C:\Program Files\program A"
echo -Windows open successfuly. Do you want to start now ?
>Pause>nul|(echo Press any key to launch the best program in the world...)
"C:\Users\program B"
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
@echo off
color 0a
title MY TITLE
echo -Welcome
echo -Do you want to do something ?
echo -I can open "an URL X" and "a program A"
pause
start https://superuser.com/
start "" "C:\Program Files\program A"
echo -Windows open successful. Do you want to start now ?
pause
echo Press any key to launch the best program in the world...
start "" "C:\Users\program B"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will test it very soon. I see that you use two " " before the actual "file path". I don't remember anything like that during my (poor) researches because I think I would have test it otherwise. What does it tells the batch/script/cmd prompt to do ? (omg I'm so lost in the vocabulary)

Comment: See [“start” command with spaces in the path](https://superuser.com/a/239572/526982)

Comment: Thanks for you help, it works perfectly now :)